# How to add reference to an external DLL from within script task?

Tags: ssis

How can I add reference to an external assembly from within a script task and deploy the package to a server along with the newly added external assembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is in reference to your other recent question, then the only proper way to get the correct version of a Word DLL on the server where you want to deploy to is to install the proper product onto the server.  Most DLL's (especially from products like Microsoft Office) are not redistributable (meaning you are not legally allowed to copy them from machine to machine without the underlying product installed).  If a DLL from Microsoft is redistributable, then there will be a document accompanying the DLL that tells which DLL's are allowed to be copied from machine to machine and what the correct process for doing so is.

If this is not in reference to that question, then can you provide more detail about what it is you are trying to do so that we can help you more.

Comment: its nothing. Just want to know more about Script Task.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SSIS 2008 (it was a bit different for SSIS 2005) - 
the referenced assembly needs to be installed into GAC (Global Assembly Cache) 
on target machine where you run the package.

Comment: well I want to install Microsoft.Interop.Word dll. how ?

Comment: I think William provided great answer for external DLLs.
I just thought based on your comment to his post, you may be interested what to do with DLL you've built yourself.